# JavaFx Binding spinner to the product of fixedValue time theValue of another spinner

Tags: java, binding, spinner, javafx-8

Binding spinner to the product of fixedValue * theValue of another spinner

I have a Label witch calculate the total from a tableView let's call it
Label totalHt witch it bounded to the sum of table's observable list items total;
another is tvaSpinner witch is editable by user to enter a TVA (10%) Value.
and the last one is 
Label totalWithTVA witch needs to be bounded to the product of:

```
 totalHt * (tvaSpinner.valueProperty()/100) .
```

Here is an example of what i want to do:

```
public class BindingSpinnerExample {
@FXML
Label totalHt;
@FXML
Spinner<Double> taxSpinner;
@FXML
Label totalWithTVA;


taxSpinner.setEditable(true);
```

i want to bound totalWithTVA to:

```
totalWithTVA = totalHt * (taxSpinner.valueProperty() / 100)
```

but i don't know how to do this biding

```
    }
```

Comment: your description is a bit hard to follow. Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also, why would you make both `totalSpinner` and `totalWithTax` spinners at all? You would never want the user to change these values, so why not just make them labels?

Answer (score 0):

This gets a bit ugly. Your `Spinner` is (presumably) a `Spinner<Double>`, so it has a `ReadOnlyObjectProperty<Double>` `valueProperty()`. The arithmetic computation methods [`multiply()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/DoubleExpression.html#multiply-javafx.beans.value.ObservableNumberValue-), `divide()`, etc are defined for `ReadOnlyDoubleProperty`, not for `ReadOnlyObjectProperty<Double>`, so you need to convert the properties into `ReadOnlyDoubleProperty`. There is a static [`ReadOnlyDoubleProperty.readOnlyDoubleProperty(ReadOnlyObjectProperty<Double>)` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/ReadOnlyDoubleProperty.html#readOnlyDoubleProperty-javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyProperty-) that can do this conversion for you.

So you need to do something like

```
DoubleBinding total = totalHtProperty.multiply(ReadOnlyDoubleProperty
    .readOnlyDoubleProperty(taxSpinner.valueProperty()).divide(100));
```

and then of course

```
totalWithTVA.textProperty().bind(total.asString());
```

where `totalHtProperty` is some kind of `DoubleExpression` with the value displayed in the `totalHt` label (I assume you are calculating this somewhere).

Here's a SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.DoubleBinding;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyDoubleProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Spinner;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BoundSpinners extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Spinner<Double> taxSpinner = new Spinner<>(0.0, 100.0, 6.0, 0.5);
        Spinner<Double> priceSpinner = new Spinner<>(0, Double.MAX_VALUE, 0, 10);

        DoubleBinding taxAmount = 
                ReadOnlyDoubleProperty.readOnlyDoubleProperty(priceSpinner.valueProperty())
                    .multiply(ReadOnlyDoubleProperty.readOnlyDoubleProperty(taxSpinner.valueProperty()).divide(100));

        Label taxLabel = new Label();
        taxLabel.textProperty().bind(taxAmount.asString("$%.2f"));

        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        root.addRow(0, new Label("Price:"), priceSpinner);
        root.addRow(1, new Label("Tax rate:"), taxSpinner);
        root.addRow(2, new Label("Tax due:"), taxLabel);

        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no bind method in spinner.valueProperty() as well as spinner.valueProperty().multiply();

Comment: Yes, you're correct. `Spinner.valueProperty()` is a `ReadOnlyProperty`. You need the `valueProperty` of the `valueFactory` instead. I updated the answer. (I still don't understand why you would use a `Spinner` though.)

Comment: Okay, i figured out what you mean by using a label, i prefered to use a spinner for my totalHt because i need the correct number format instead of Label's String. But sure there a string formatter to do so.

Comment: Also there is no multiply methode for spinner class.

Comment: I have updated the quesiton to be a little bit more clear.

Comment: Updated the answer completely.